# Can sheriff replenish his extra life point?

Tags: bang

Sheriff always starts with one extra health point. Can this extra point be replenished through Beer or through other means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beer can replenish the extra bullet that the Sheriff gets. From the Bang! rulebook:

> The Sheriff plays the game with one additional bullet: if his character card shows three bullets, he is considered for all effects to have four; if he has four bullets, then the Sheriff plays with five.

"All effects" includes Beer.